# Iframe not sizing right

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<html>
<script>
document.write("<iframe id='theframe' src='http://www.website.com?testvr=" + testvr + " height='900' width='500'></iframe>");
</script>
</html>
```

The iframe is added, but at 500 x 150 and not at 900 x 500. This sized fine when the iframe was inside the body tags and only does this when using document.write. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, the correct way to apply styling is with the style attribute.

```
<iframe id='theframe' src='yourComplexSrc' style='height:900px; width:500px;'></iframe>
```

*Best Practice:* separate your styling from your markup. (style should go to a different stylesheet file)

but, the problem with your code is that after the `src` value, you don't have a closing tag.
so eventually, this should work:

```
document.write("<iframe id='theframe' src='http://www.website.com?testvr=" + testvr + "' height='900' width='500'></iframe>");
```

Comment: he is also using some parameter in the src

Comment: Thanks, suppose I got mixed up with all the quotation marks. Also I don't think the height/width attributes of an iframe are deprecated as they are in other elements, as I usually do use CSS.